# find_if to seach abstract object list with std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a list which contains abstract objects and now I need to use a string search to the list to compare object's name and the string. Here is the abstract class.

```
class ShaderEffect {
  std::string subroutine_name_;
 public:
  [[nodiscard]] std::string GetSubroutineName() const {
    return subroutine_name_;
  }
  virtual void Set(const Params& t) = 0;
};
```

Here is the how I use find_if, but I got compilation error says
**"cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const ShaderEffect &'"**

```
const std::string& effect;
std::array<std::unique_ptr<ShaderEffect>, 10> all_effects_;
auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(all_effects_), std::end(all_effects_),
                         [effect](const ShaderEffect& f) -> bool {
                           return f.GetSubroutineName() == effect;
                         });
```

Comment: `const ShaderEffect& f` -> `const std::unique_ptr<ShaderEffect>& f` (and so `f.` -> `f->`).

Comment: Thanks so much for such quick respond, I felt stupid that I missed the unique_ptr part

Comment: You could also use `const auto&` if you are using c++14 and up.